# Ajax error in gridview IE 9 + .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have updated recently to IE 9 and I'm getting some strange issues.
I have a page with a Gridview in an updatepanel, grid wich has a commandfield for edit/delete records. The command fields is using image for button type. When I click on the button, I'm getting a Javascript error saying that:

```
Error: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

This error only appears when I use the following combination (.NET 3.5 + IE 9 + Image type buttons). If I'm using .NET 4.0 or IE 8 or Link/Button type buttons I'm not getting the same error.

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/undo.jpg" 
     DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/delete.jpg" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit_1.jpg" 
     InsertVisible="False" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
     UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/accept.jpg">
</asp:CommandField>
```

Do you know how can I avoid this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have found the solution. I have set ScriptMode="Release" in ScriptManager. Default Value is Auto. It solved the my problem. You can also used auto for the same but you have to set 

  

When retail is set to true, ASP.NET disables certain configuration settings such as trace output, custom errors, and debug capabilities.just set retail = true you can use ScriptMode= Auto.

Comment: +1 !! I had the exact same error when using a standard ImageButton inside an UpdatePanel. It was not part of a GridView. Setting `ScriptMode="Release"` in ScriptManager solved it.

Comment: I advice everyone with UpdatePanels on their pages, trying to make their websites compatible with IE10 to try this suggestion when they run into alot of problems (__postback is undefined, parameters being null,..). It fixed ALOT of errors for me and saved me a lot of time, for which I thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue also. I am using .NET 3.5 + IE 9 + Image type buttons. The error was gone after I removed the updatepanel

Comment: You can use the [sollution from Mohan Prajapati](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137971/ajax-error-in-gridview-ie-9-net-3-5/6679226#6679226), and it will work also inside an UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep the updatepanel you can use the TemplateField instead of ButtonField or CommandField.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contacts">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../../images/icons/contacts.png" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" CommandName="yourCommand" runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


Dim row As GridViewRow = uxgvServiceUsers.Rows(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument))

If e.CommandName.Trim.Equals("yourCommand") Then
                Response.Redirect("./Page.aspx")
```